# Hybrid Android App - Can you clear app cache from within the app itself?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, sapui5

We have an Andriod app built using SAP Cloud Platforms Hybrid App Toolkit which incorporates Javascript and Cordova.

An issue is arising whereby requests from the app are getting stuck in the request queue. The solution is to manually clear the app cache.

As we'd rather not give our end-user the extra hassle, is there a way to clear the app cache from within the app itself?

So far I've tried this to no avail

```
window.cache.clear();
```

Also tried this cordova command..

```
flushStore: function () {
        localStorage.clear() 
        // FLUSH Offline store (Offline store updates ECC)
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            store.flush(function () {
                resolve();
            }, function () {
                reject();

            }, null, sap.hybrid.progressCallback);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an hybrid app it's pretty much the same as opening the app in a browser. It also depends on the cache you're implementing. You're probablly just using localStorage, so for that, is as easy as using `localStorage.clear()`

Comment: Thanks you... let's give that a go.

Comment: localStorage.clear() had no effect. Is that a Javascipt or cordove command?

Comment: localStorage is a browser api that you have access to when using cordova. A few recommendations, post the part of the code where you think something is being saved to the cache. Or try implementing localStorage instead of whatever you're using. It really depends on what you're implementing. If you have more info that you think might be usefull please post it!

Comment: Hi @Gabriel Tortomano. I will try again from the Cordova section of the code. This is an app developed in SAP WEB IDE using the SAP Hybrid App Toolkit, SAP mobile services etc, so we don't have info on where something saves to the cache.

Comment: localStorage.clear() didn't work either. Please see code in the edited description.